# Match all values str column dataframe with other dataframe str column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes:

Dataframe 1:

```
ITEM ID TEXT
1       some random words
2       another word
3       blah 
4       random words
```

Dataframe 2:

```
INDEX INFO
1     random
3     blah
```

I would like to match the values from the INFO column (of dataframe 2) with the TEXT column of dataframe 1. If there is a match, I would like to see a new column with a "1".

Something like this:

```
ITEM ID TEXT                  MATCH
1       some random words       1
2       another word  
3       blah                    1
4       random words            1
```

I was able to create a match per value of the INFO column that I'm looking for with this line of code:

`dataframe1.loc[dataframe1['TEXT'].str.contains('blah'), 'MATCH'] = '1'`

However, in reality, my real dataframe 2 has 5000 rows. So I cannot manually copy paste all of this. But basically I'm looking for something like this:

`dataframe1.loc[dataframe1['TEXT'].str.contains('Dataframe2[INFO]'), 'MATCH'] = '1'`

I hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: Making sure that `MATCH` is a binary value - it either matches or it doesn't. For instance, if `TEXT` where "some random blah" then `MATCH` is still "1".  Also, what about if `TEXT` is "randomized blahblahblah" - is that a match?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification question! Yes, it is binary, if ```TEXT``` were "some random blah" then it would indeed still be "1". And also yes to the second question, it would also be a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

Code:

```
dfA['MATCH']    = dfA['TEXT'].apply(lambda x: min(len([ y for y in dfB['INFO'] if y in x]), 1))
```

Output:

```
   ITEM ID               TEXT  MATCH
0        1  some random words      1
1        2       another word      0
2        3               blah      1
3        4       random words      1
```

It's a 0 if it's not a match, but that's easy enough to weed out.

There may be a better / faster native solution, but it gets the job done by iterating over both the 'TEXT' column and the 'INFO'.  Depending on your use case, it may be fast enough.

Looks like `.map()` in lieu of `.apply()` would work just as well.  Could make a difference in timing, again, based on your use case.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  How long does it take to run the 5,000 rows?

Answer (score 0):

Updated to take into account string contains instead of exact match...

You could get the unique values from the column in the first dataframe convert them to list and then use eval method on the second with Column.str.contains on that list.

```
unique = df1['TEXT'].unique().tolist()
df2.eval("Match=Text.str.contains('|'.join(@unique))")
```